# VSTS/TFS Git Branching Strategy and Continuous Integration

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Our company had been using a git branching strategy that kept a long-running sprint work branch around that looked something like this:

```
master
  \
   Sprint
     \
      Feature1
      Feature2
```

With the current sprint, we switched to having a new branch with a new name for each sprint:

```
master
  \
   Sprint123
     \
      Feature1
      Feature2
```

With this change some pain points arise:

1. Policy has to be set up each time a new Sprint### branch is created (which includes continuous integration and pull request settings).
2. Build definitions have triggers which still work fine via wildcard ("Sprint*"), but the repository source setting for the build doesn't support wildcards.

I've been through the VSTS documentation, but I feel like I've missed something on how to set this up to have a new branch per sprint (which is in line with VSTS branching strategy documentation).

So, the questions are:

**Our expectation was that the branch that triggers the build is the one that is built. Is this possible?**

**What is the recommendation for setting branch policy each time a new branch is created off of master? Should we just expect that we will have to configure all of the settings manually every time?**

Comment: I'll bite... what is the advantage of this branch naming convention?

Comment: The Pull Request policy is responsible for triggering the build when a PR is raised.  With that in mind the trigger settings on the build definition itself have no impact.  The branch that is built as part of the PR will be something like refs/pulls/23/merge.  

I believe wild card branch policies are coming in the not too distant future which should enable this flow for you.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger That is a good question. The intent was 1) To stop the long-lived branch from getting so far behind master branch (for hotfix PR's) and 2) Allow a sprint branch to hang around if need be while another sprint is started. It may be that we need to rethink those items.

Answer (score 3):

We've published [guidance on Git branch strategy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/git-branching-guidance). The sibling answer which points at TFVC is incorrect.

We don't recommend long-running development branches for most teams. Instead, keep a clean master and use short-lived topic branches. Then, you won't need to keep creating and deleting policies, build definitions, etc.

If you must keep using long-lived branches for some reason, consider using slashes in the names of branches, e.g. `sprints/s100`. We have a REST API already (and soon, admin UI) to set policies on a [prefix-matching basis](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/policy/settings#git-ref-scope), stopping at `/`s. So, you could set up branch policy on `sprints/` and it would get automatically applied to `sprints/s100`, `sprints/s101`, etc.

Comment: It should be noted that the commonly-recommended git branch strategies (like gitflow) use a single long-running `develop` branch for a reason; and that MS's choice to create contrary recommendations that cater to the feature set they've chosen to develop in their server products does nothing to remove that reason. Perhaps MS would do better to build features that work well with the tools they wish to integrate

Comment: Unclear where our guidance is contradictory. Can you point me to that so I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You stated that you recommend creating feature branches off of a clean `master`.  This is contrary to the `gitflow` approach - which as far as I am aware is the most commonly recommended and/or "borrowed-from" strategy in the git world - in which feature branches are made from a long-lived `development` (or `develop`) branch, and `master` consists entirely of production release versions.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. The important point here is, branching topics off a clean central branch is essential. GitFlow uses `develop` by convention; many teams use `master`. There's no restriction or problem in our product that prevents using GitFlow.

Comment: Ok, if you're *not* recommending against the use of a long-lived branch like `develop`, that's good to hear...  Applying that to OP's situation, the `sprint` branches are essentially `develop` with a different name.  It's the use of "medium-life" branches - long-enough to aggregate features but still replaced with the passing of each sprint - that is somewhat less typical

Comment: 100% agree. If I didn't state it strongly enough, I'll edit: I *don't* think the `sprints/*` scheme is a good one.

Comment: This conversation is very helpful. I've un-accepted this answer as the correct one, as it doesn't jibe with the conversation. I don't have the time at the moment, but I'd like to summarize the gist of the conversation in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended branching strategy is always **use the same branch even for new sprints**. As [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-strategically), you can always use `development` branch for different sprints.

Of cause, you can use your branching strategy if the codes are quite different between two sprints. But the disadvantages as:

1. Set branch policy each time when you create new branch.
2. As time goes on, there will has amount of branches `sprint*`, it’s not good to trace the whole project versions easily.

Finally, for your questions (if you still need your current strategy):

1. Yes, you can still use the format `Sprint*` in build definition Triggers Tab, then your new created branches Sprint### will also suitable for CI build. And get sources step for build definition won’t affect your CI build, the repo and branch select only for manually queue build.
2. You need to set branch policy manually for the new created branches every time.

Comment: The "Branch strategically" article is very helpful. It is unfortunate that it lives under the TFVC section. We have stayed away from that section after getting our wires crossed, initially thinking that we were looking at git-related info.

Comment: I've read more closely and I'm finding conflicting information. I believe that it is the difference between git and TFVC recommendations. The following guidance only recommends long-lived branches for feature branches, and for those, only until they are no longer needed: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/git-branching-guidance

Comment: This article is definitely TFVC-focused. Our article about Git branching strategy is here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/git-branching-guidance

Comment: @Marina-MSFT When I refer to it living under TFVC, take a look at the "Branch strategically" page. At the top of the left pane, the article is under the "Team Services & TFS \ TFVC" section. Click that "TFVC" dropdown and see that there is a Git section. I understand that a lot of work is in progress on VSTS/TFS systems, but the TFVC and Git documentation could use some refactoring.